# How to add dynamic URLs for different cities of a country Django-leaflet

Tags: django, url, leaflet, shapefile, geodjango

I have a shapefile of a country on districts level. I want every district to be clickable on shapefile on Leaflet (Django) and get to another URL where it shows stats of that city or district on another page. How can I set dynamic URLs like each district have a unique id so URL will be based on id? I don't know how to get this process done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this answer:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42631/go-to-the-url-on-click-with-geojson

You want to set a click event on the layer. When clicked, run a function that opens a url based on one of attributes in your shapefile.

When instantiating the layer use:

```
onEachFeature: openShapeURL
```

Something like this:

```
function openShapeURL(e) {
            window.open('http://www.google.com' + feature.properties.<YOUR-VARIABLE-HERE>,'_blank');
        }
```